# Custom post type template - add banner under heading

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to add  tag in CUSTOM POST TYPE (news). Problem is that I dont know how. I'm not a developer of WP Theme.

I need to add it here: [HERE](https://www.komora.cz/news_category/aktuality-z-legislativy/)

As you can see its a custom post type with posts, but I need to add the  only to this subcategory (aktuality-z-legislativy) somewhere under heading. How can I do that ?

Comment: Your site dosent look like wordpress, It uses some wordpress file structure but seems heavily modified. Try contacting the theme/site developer for help

Comment: it is WordPress but the OP has chosen an unusual folder structure combined with the Autoptimize plugin.

Comment: @samm-foolt do you know about the theme template hierarchy? You can duplicate the template and give the filename a particular name that matches that specific term so it only loads for that term, then add the banner to it, probably something like `taxonomy-news_category-1849.php`

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you I solved this problem as you wrote and its working :)

Comment: can you post what you did below as an answer? I can't upvote and give you points for a comment

Comment: You need to create a separate template for custom post type where all single post of that post type will be displayed right??

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I duplicated taxonomy.php template in theme folder and named it taxonomy-news-business.php then I edited the code inside this template

So the result is that now all posts in CUSTOM POST TYPE with slug news with category businesss are displayed according this template because taxonomy template hierarchy in WordPress is taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php